# How do I store c++ class objects as an array?

Tags: c++

I need to create class that has startpoint name, endpoint name, and slack value ( from text file). The objects of the class has to be stored as an array. After parsing the file , I need to loop through the stored objects and print the values.

Questions I have:

Q1) How do I store objects as an array?

Q2) How can a file be parsed inside the class to have startpoint name, endpoint name and a slack value assigned?

Text file:

```
Startpoint: reg_4A

Endpoint: reg_49A

Path Type: max

  Point                                                               Incr       Path

  clock clk (rise edge)                                               0.000        0.000 

  clock network delay (propagated)                                    1.566        1.566 

  i0001016/Y (BUF_X4)                                                 0.086  &     1.885  f

  U20/Y (NAND_X1)                                                     0.043  &     1.928  r
  statistical adjustment                                                  0.016     -0.157

  slack (VIOLATED)                                                                  -0.157



Startpoint: reg_10A

Endpoint: reg_49A

Path Type: max
  Point                                             Incr       Path


  clock ck_pl2_clk (rise edge)                      0.000        0.000

  clock network delay (propagated)                  1.566        1.566

  reg_10A/CK (DFFQ_X6)                              0.000        1.566  r

  i0000502/Y (INV_X6LVT)                            0.022  &     1.744  r

  data required time                                           3.553

  data arrival time                                           -3.677

  statistical adjustment                            0.016       -0.108

  slack (VIOLATED)                                            -0.108
```

Comment: An array is an array is an array... The type of the elements doesn't matter. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your attempt and mention the problem you are facing with your approach

Comment: C++ is not best tool to parse text files, so unless it is some external requirement I recommend to use some scripting languages like `python`, `ruby`, etc

Comment: That file is awful to parse even in parsing-friendly languages, but you need to start with studying the format's formal definition (if you're lucky and it has one).

Comment: I would suggest regex would be your best option to extract the bits you need from this file

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array with [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) if you know the size a priori. If the container should change its size use [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

```cpp
struct Object {
    Object(const std::string &st, const std::string &en, double sl) :
        startpoint(st), endpoint(en), slack(sl) {}
    std::string startpoint;
    std::string endpoint;
    std::string slack;
};

std::vector<Object> objects;
objects.emplace_back(startpoint, endpoint, slack);
```

You can use this regular expression

```
Startpoint: ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\n\nEndpoint: ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\n\nPath Type: [a-zA-Z0-9_]+\n+  Point +Incr +Path\n+  (?:[a-zA-Z0-9_()/ ]+ +(?:-?\d+\.\d{3} *[&rf]? *){1,2} *\n+)*  slack \(VIOLATED\) +(-?\d.\d{3})
```

with [regex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) to extract the values

```cpp
std::string file("Text");
std::regex re("(\w)(\w)xt");
auto words_begin = std::sregex_iterator(file.begin(), file.end(), re);
auto words_end = std::sregex_iterator();
for (auto it = words_begin; it != words_end; ++it) {
    if (it->size() == 3) {
        std::cout << (*it)[1] << '\n'; // contains whole match "Text"
        std::cout << (*it)[2] << '\n'; // contains first group "T"
        std::cout << (*it)[3] << '\n'; // contains second group "e"
    }
}
```

Here is an example:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <set>
#include <utility>

struct Object {
    Object(const std::string &st, const std::string &en, double sl) :
        startpoint(st), endpoint(en), slack(sl) {}
    std::string startpoint;
    std::string endpoint;
    double slack;
};


int main() {
    std::string file(R"(Startpoint: reg_4A

Endpoint: reg_49A

Path Type: max

  Point                                                               Incr       Path

  clock clk (rise edge)                                               0.000        0.000 

  clock network delay (propagated)                                    1.566        1.566 

  i0001016/Y (BUF_X4)                                                 0.086  &     1.885  f

  U20/Y (NAND_X1)                                                     0.043  &     1.928  r
  statistical adjustment                                                  0.016     -0.157

  slack (VIOLATED)                                                                  -0.157



Startpoint: reg_10A

Endpoint: reg_49A

Path Type: max
  Point                                             Incr       Path


  clock ck_pl2_clk (rise edge)                      0.000        0.000

  clock network delay (propagated)                  1.566        1.566

  reg_10A/CK (DFFQ_X6)                              0.000        1.566  r

  i0000502/Y (INV_X6LVT)                            0.022  &     1.744  r

  data required time                                           3.553

  data arrival time                                           -3.677

  statistical adjustment                            0.016       -0.108

  slack (VIOLATED)                                            -0.108)");

    std::regex re(R"(Startpoint: ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\n\nEndpoint: ([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\n\nPath Type: [a-zA-Z0-9_]+\n+  Point +Incr +Path\n+  (?:[a-zA-Z0-9_()/ ]+ +(?:-?\d+\.\d{3} *[&rf]? *){1,2} *\n+)*  slack \(VIOLATED\) +(-?\d.\d{3}))");

    std::vector<Object> objects;

    std::for_each(std::sregex_iterator(file.begin(), file.end(), re), std::sregex_iterator(), [&objects](const auto &it) {
        if (it.size() == 4) {
            objects.emplace_back(it[1], it[2], std::stod(it[3]));
        }
    });

    for (const auto &object : objects) {
        std::cout << object.startpoint << ' ' << object.endpoint << ' ' << object.slack << '\n';
    }
}
```

with output

```
reg_4A reg_49A -0.157
reg_10A reg_49A -0.108
```

Comment: Thanks for the elegant approach. So if I want to open the file in the main function rather than passing the contents as a string. Will the following be okay ? 
std::ifstream file(timing.txt);

if (file.is_open()) {
std::string line;

while (getline(file, line)) {
std::for_each(std::sregex_iterator(line.begin(), line.end(), re), std::sregex_iterator(), [&objects](const auto &it) {
/* your code */
}

Comment: Why don't you just try it?